# How to deploy PHP7 with MongoDB ext on Heroku?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, composer-php, php-7, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to deploy an app on Heroku and I'm running into issues related to conflicting composer dependencies. It's working fine from my local dev machine, I can `composer update` without any issue.

Here is a sample of my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "php": "7.1.*",
    "ext-mongo": "*",
    "ext-mongodb": "^1.2",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
    "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.1",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.2",
    "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.0-beta2",
    "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "^1.5",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.4",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.1"
},
```

...and here is the error output from Heroku:

```
> Loading repositories with available runtimes and extensions
> Updating dependencies
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
>   Problem 1
>     - Installation request for doctrine/annotations v1.4.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/annotations[v1.4.0].
>     - Installation request for twig/twig v2.3.2 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.3.2].
>     - Conclusion: don't install php 7.1.3
>     - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb 1.4.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.4.0].
>     - doctrine/annotations v1.4.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> satisfiable by php[5.6.30, 7.0.15, 7.0.16, 7.0.17, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 7.1.3].
>     - don't install php 7.1.1|don't install php 5.5.38
>     - don't install php 7.1.2|don't install php 5.5.38
>     - don't install php 7.0.15|don't install php 5.5.38
>     - don't install php 7.0.16|don't install php 5.5.38
>     - don't install php 7.0.17|don't install php 5.5.38
>         - ext-mongo 1.6.14 requires php 5.5.* -> satisfiable by php[5.5.38].
>     - doctrine/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> satisfiable by ext-mongo[1.6.14].
>     - ext-mongo 1.6.14 requires php 5.6.* -> satisfiable by php[5.6.30].
>     - Conclusion: don't install php 5.6.30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bigger problem. Let's divide it into two parts:

**Part 1:**

Ext-mongo is a [legacy driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) that does not exist for PHP7.x. But Doctrine-ODM requires ext-mongo. The workaround is to use an adapter that provides an interface for the old driver that uses the new [MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php). There is an explanation in the [Doctrine-ODM documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html#using-php-7), but this explanation isn't up-to-date and therefore incomplete/incorrect.

In your case, it means that you remove `"ext-mongo"` and `"ext-mongodb"` from the `"require"` section of your composer file and keep the `"alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter"` (The adapter will require itself `"ext-mongodb"` - the new driver.) Unfortunately, this still won't work and brings us to Part 2.

**Part 2:**

Integrating the *alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter* as it is currently provided by Packagist will create a composer dependency conflict. There is some discussion about [exactly this problem](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter/issues/67) and also if this might be a general composer issue ([see here](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter/issues/67)). Also, several solutions are suggested. [One solution](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter/issues/67#issuecomment-187444756) works for me (I'm also deploying on Heroku):

In the composer.json of the *alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter* replace:

```
"provide": {
    "ext-mongo": "1.6.14"
},
```

by:

```
"replace": {
    "ext-mongo": "1.6.14"
},
```

On GitHub, the [master branch of *alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter*](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter) uses the "provide"-version, but there is also a [composer-replace](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter/tree/composer-replace) branch that uses the "replace"-version. Unfortunately, this branch isn't kept up-to-date.

You can use that "replace" branch as repository for *alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter* in your composer file:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter"
        }
    ],
"require": {
    "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "dev-composer-replace",
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could fork the master branch, replace "provide" by "replace" and use that fork as repository.